# Zeros of holomorphic function have limit point outside domain

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is exercise 10.20 in Rudin's R&CA.

> Suppose $f \in H(U)$, $g \in H(U)$, and neither $f$ nor $g$ has a zero in $U$. If
>   $$
> \frac{f'}{f}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{g'}{g}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \quad (n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots)
> $$
>
> Find another simple relation between $f$ and $g$.

EDIT: I didn't know $U$ is the unit disc when I posted this. I thought it could be any open set.

$0$ is a limit point of the zeros of the function $\varphi = f'/f - g'/g$. However, $0$ isn't necessarily in $U$. I'm not sure how to deal with it if $0$ is a pole or essential singularity of $\varphi$, and I couldn't find much info about limit points of zeros that are outside the domain of a holomorphic function. Ultimately, I suspect $\varphi = 0$ everywhere and thus $g = \lambda f$ for some constant $\lambda$.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better approach here? Thanks.

Comment: What is $U$? Any open set?

Comment: @mrf This is all what the exercise says. It doesn't specify what $U$ is, so assume it can be any open set that contains $1, 1/2, \ldots$.

Comment: I just browsed through my copy. It seems as $U$ in fact *is* the unit disc. Check p110 (at least in my edition, look for "unit disc" in the index).

Comment: @mrf Yes, Davide Giraudo just pointed this out. The exercise becomes very easy once you know this. I spent so much time on nothing. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h:=f/g$ (well defined). Its derivative is $0$ and if $U$ is the open unit disk, we get $h'\equiv 0$ hence $f$ and $g$ are proportional.

Comment: How do you know the derivative is $0$? We don't know if $U$ is the open disc. $f$ and $g$ may not be defined at $0$.

Comment: In the previous exercises, $U$ is assumed to be the open unit disk. I guessed (but I may be wrong) that it's still the case in this exercise.

Comment: Gosh you're right. And I've been researching this for 2 hours to no avail. Such an easy exercise once you know $U$ is the unit disc. Thanks.